# How does finishing the Trial of the Sword affect the Master Sword?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

Trial of the Sword is a lot harder than the Ganon Blights or calamity Ganon himself. What does upgrading the Master Sword do?

Answer (score 6):

Completing each level of the Trial of the Sword will add 10 damage to the Master Sword (which starts out at 30).

You will notice that when fighting Calamity Ganon monsters with the Master Sword, it will start glowing blue and its damage will jump to 60 points (along with a nice bonus to durability).

Fully completing the Trial of the Sword will put the sword permanently in this state (glowing blue, 60 damage, 200 durability).  There will no longer be an additional damage boost when fighting Calamity Ganon monsters, however.

Comment: This answer fails to take into account the feeling of intense satisfaction after completing all three trials :)

Comment: @scohe001 while very true, that's not exactly related to the sword itself :P

Comment: I think the boosted durability is 188 and not 200 (I have seen answers of both online, but I think 200 is a rounding). This page goes through extensive testing which is why I'm inclinced to believe 188: https://www.reddit.com/r/Breath_of_the_Wild/comments/hh60mo/why_the_master_sword_has_188_durability_and_why/